# How To Permanently keep port 80 open On Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I just installed Ubuntu Web Server and at the end of the install, it mentioned to me that I could go to IP address. Did that and got the great saying "can't connect". I figure port 80 didn't get open. So I found this and ran "sudo phython3 -m http.server 80 and I get the directory listing of the server. But after I ran it, it seems like it froze on me, how do I get out of it? Next question: I then ran sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT and then sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent and then rebooted and then I type in the IP address again, and that darn sign came back up "sorry can't be connected". So what am I doing wrong and how can it get permanently stay? Thanks.

Comment: When you say you installed "Ubuntu Web Server", do you mean you installed Apache on Ubuntu? Or something else? There are several web servers available for Ubuntu and I'd rather not give you the wrong set of directions 

Comment: Just curious: Why do you need port 80 (http) open? Do you have any reason not to use port 443 (https)?

Answer (score 2):

UFW is part of the standard Ubuntu 20.04 installation and should be present on your system. If for some reason it is not installed, you can install the package by typing:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ufw
```

You can list all application profiles available on your server by typing:

```
$ sudo ufw app list
```

Depending on the packages installed on your system, the output will look similar to the following:

**Output**

```
Available applications:
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSHCopy
```

To find more information about a specific profile and included rules, use the following command:

```
$ sudo ufw app info 'Nginx Full'
```

The output shows that the ‘Nginx Full’ profile opens ports 80 and 443.

```
Profile: Nginx Full
Title: Web Server (Nginx, HTTP + HTTPS)
Description: Small, but very powerful and efficient web server

Ports:
  80,443/tcp
```

If you’re connecting to your Ubuntu from a remote location, before enabling the UFW firewall, you must explicitly allow incoming SSH connections. Otherwise, you will no longer be able to connect to the machine.

To configure your UFW firewall to allow incoming SSH connections, type the following command:

```
$ sudo ufw allow ssh
```

Now that the firewall is configured to allow incoming SSH connections, you can enable it by typing:

```
$ sudo ufw enable

Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
```

You will be warned that enabling the firewall may disrupt existing ssh connections, just type y and hit Enter.

Depending on the applications that run on the system, you may also need to open other ports. The general syntax to open a port is as follows:

```
$ ufw allow port_number/protocol
```

Below are a few ways on how to allow HTTP connections.

The first option is to use the service name. UFW checks the /etc/services file for the port and protocol of the specified service:

```
$ sudo ufw allow http
```

You can also specify the port number, and the protocol:

```
$ sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
```

When no protocol is given, UFW creates rules for both tcp and udp.

Another option is to use the application profile; in this case, ‘Nginx HTTP’:

```
$ sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'
```

UFW also support another syntax for specifying the protocol using the proto keyword:

```
$ sudo ufw allow proto tcp to any port 80
```

Comment: matigo 7- To answer your question, as I stated I installed the Ubuntu Webserver on my  Oracle VM.  I did everything right, my only problem is that port 80 will not stay open after I boot up or reboot.  So how do I keep it in there?